# How to get the websocket url after login to a website using JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket

I am trying to get the websocket url from a website and I know that it is only possible after successful login to the website.

My code connects to the website fine using typescript and playwright, but I just don't know how to get the wss full address.

Using Chrome Dev Tools, I can get the web socket address, but I need to get it through code.

Here is what I tried without success.

```
import wait from "./lib/wait.js";
import { chromium } from "playwright";

const baseUrl = "https://thewebsite.com/ptb/live/detail/18280";


export async function run() {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 });
  const context = await browser.newContext({
userAgent:
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36",
  });
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto(`${baseUrl}`);

  await page.type('input[id="username"]', "myLogin");
  await page.type('input[id="password"]', "myPassword");

  const usernameValue = await page.inputValue("#username");
  const passwordValue = await page.inputValue("#password");
  console.log(usernameValue);
  console.log(passwordValue);  

  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Enter' }).click();
  await wait(12);

  console.log("You are logged in...");

  // Intercept WebSocket connections
  page.on('websocket', ws => {
    console.log('WebSocket URL:', ws.url());
  });

}


run()
  .then(() => {})
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

The output is just the console logs for login credentials and the "You are logged in...", but no wss address.

How can I get it?